# Creating a SQLParameter from an array for an IN clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an array of integers. I want to use that array in my selectCommand to form an "IN" clause ("WHERE Cli.ID IN (1,2,3,4)"). I have tried to turn the array into a string (code below) but that (reasonably enough) doesn't work.

I found [this KB article from 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555266) but the proposed workaround made my eyes bleed.

Is there an easy and elegant way to do this that I'm missing? Surely it's a common enough thing to want to do?

```
        string iDlist = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < MyIDs.Length; i++)
        {
            iDlist += Convert.ToString(MyIDs[i]) + (i == 0 ? "" : ",");
        }

        this.sqlDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.CommandText = StandardQuery + @" where Cli.ID in (@iDlist)";

        this.sqlDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        this.sqlDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@iDlist", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        this.sqlDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Parameters["@iDlist"].Value = iDlist;
```